# Upload encrypted Word document to Google Cloud storage

Tags: java, netbeans, google-cloud-storage

I have created a Java desktop application that stores encrypted files on the desktop. I have been tasked with uploading a Word document that is encrypted by this application to store on the Google Cloud Storage (free personal Google Cloud storage account).

Is this possible, what jar files are needed and what would the coding be to connect to the Google Cloud storage to achieve this? Or is there a better way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a blob in the Google Cloudstorage, you can view all the configuration here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

For your pourpouse and if you have control over the google account configuration, you can upload the documents to a drive account of the app using the drive api for app engine, this conmmunication it´s encripted so it´s easier for you to implement. The problem is that you have to use an allowed authentication like oauth2

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response. I appreciate the help. I have looked at google drive and seem to be a bit lost in terms of how to connect and upload a file to the google drive from a java desktop application.

Any further advice on this maybe... All the help would be tremendously appreciative and life saving :) :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "free personal Google Cloud Storage account", I suspect that you may be confusing the enterprise blob storage product, "Google Cloud Storage", with the free, personal document storage product, Google Drive.

https://www.google.com/drive/

If your use case is primarily to store, view, edit, and share documents, you're looking for Google Drive. If you are looking to create a program which can store a large number of arbitrarily large objects of any type (documents included), you are likely looking for Google Cloud Storage.